# Symfony2 error Flushing an entitiy within the preUpdate event of another entiity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a reletivly simple change logging class that stores the date, an integer to indicate the type of change and 2 varchar(50)s that hold the old and new data for the change.

I can create and populate an instance of the class but when  I come to flush it I get an "Error: Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting!" error.

I've read about the Xdebug issue and configured the max nests up to 200 but as you can see this isn't enough. The save process should be very simple and there should be no need for so many nested functions, so increasing it further will just hide the problem, whatever it is. I have far more complicated classes in this app that persisit and flush without a problem.

The issue is always at

*NormalizerFormatter ->normalize ()
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 4912  -*

Having looked at this a bit more I think the issue may be that the change instance is created and saved during the preUpdate event of another class:

```
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
    if ($entity instanceof Property) {
        $entityManager = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $changeArray = $eventArgs->getEntityChangeSet();
        foreach ($changeArray as $field => $values) {
            $eventType = "";
            switch ($field) {
                case 'price' :
                    $eventType = PropertyEvent::EVENTTYPE_PRICE;
                BREAK;    
                case 'status' :
                    $eventType = PropertyEvent::EVENTTYPE_STATUS;
                BREAK;    
            }
            if ($eventType != "") {
                $event = new PropertyEvent($entity->getID(), $eventType, $values[0], $values[1]);
                $entityManager->persist($event);
                $entityManager->flush();
            }
        }
        $entity->setUpdatedDate();
    }

}
```

Why would that be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine only has one lifecycle event process so regardless of the entity you're using adding a flush within a lifecycle event will send you back round the loop and into your event handler again... and again ... and...

Have a look at this blog post 
http://mightyuhu.github.io/blog/2012/03/27/doctrine2-event-listener-persisting-a-new-entity-in-onflush/

Basically the answer is to use

```
$eventManager -> removeEventListener('preUpdate', $this);
```

to remove the event. Then create the new entity, persist, flush and finally re-attach the event you are in.

```
$eventManager -> addEventListener('preUpdate', $this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the `$entity->setUpdatedDate();` call, which probably calls another update event and re-calls your handler.